# As for "beholder", first "e" is pronounced as schwa or i?

Tags: pronunciation

I found beholder is pronounced like [bihóuldər] but I heard some speaker in the VOA pronounced it like [bəhóuldər]. Which one is right? Are native speakers confused with them?

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is right?

[bihóuldər] is technically the correct pronunciation.

> Are native speakers confused with them?

As a native speaker, I would say no. Furthermore, I would also point out that it seems very common to use a "lazy" pronunciation and to say [bəhóuldər] (at least in the United States).

Comment: Exactly. In speech, vowels are often "weakened" (not a technical term, but you know what I mean—not as distinct as the official pronunciation)  Still, I doubt you would hear even an American say "Behold!" with a schwa. (But then, you might never hear an American say "Behold!"—it seems to us too quaint/theatrical.)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Depends on theatrics, definitely. =P

Comment: I say behold with a schwa. behold with an /i/ sounds like a place you keep your honey. :-)

Comment: @hunter Lol I was actually thinking the same thing =P

Answer (score 1):

To my (American) ear, both pronunciations are correct.  I use both pronunciations myself.  I prefer the unstressed first syllable (with the schwa).